# External Reference to Richfaces modal

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

I need to get a

```
<rich:modalPanel id="mod1" .../>
```

component to load an external page on "show" action, defined as:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="link" id="l1" reRender="mod1" oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('mod1')">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mybean.someParam}" value="#{myOtherbean.someOtherparam}" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

. My first try was with

```
<rich:modalPanel id="mod1">
    <ui:include src="#{mybean.generateURL}"/>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

but it just throws me a 404 page not found error, typing the generated URL directly into the address bar works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what's causing the problem , or what's the correct way to do this?

The system is running on seam/richfaces.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to load an external website into a modal? Eg. like an iframe?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. <iframe> is doing perfectly fine for me as you and Bozho suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `<x:include>` to include external pages. You have two options:

- As Damo suggested in the comments, use an `<iframe>` inside the modal
- use a bean of yours to load the contents of the target url (via `URL.openConnection()`) and output them in a page, which you can then include.

Comment: Thanks, using <iframe> is working perfectly fine. 

Pardon me for being an idiot here, I'm bad at web devs, so:
 - I don't really get why you can't use the <x:include> tags, is it something to do with the page rendering phases? 
 - I can't figure out how to use approach 2 either.